# django, accessing meta properties outside of the page that generates them

Tags: django, django-views

So basically, I'm using the `PersistentRemoteUser` middelware in django to handle authentication requests through a login page that is monitored by `apache` using `pubcookie`

I can do the basic `user.is_authenticated` bit's fine, but my problem comes from the fact that I have 2 types of users that require two different kinds of authentication. I have my admin users that require authenticating with 2 factor authentication, and standard users that use only user/password,

The authentication type can easily be viewed on the login page itself by accessing: `self.request.META['AUTH_TYPE'] which will read as either "SecureID" or "NetID" depending on the`authtype`.

But I need to be able to perform a check on different pages to see if the user authenticated with `secureid` or `netid` to determine what parts of a page are viewable, or if they are allowed to see the page at all. But the `meta data` does not exist outside of the initial login page, only the `request.user` data, which does not, unless i'm missing something, contain any type of `auth_type`.

is it possible to either access the `metadata` from another page, or save the users authtype to some kind of `post` or `session` variable that gets carried around for the session?

Sorry if this question is a bit...dumb, I'm still fairly new to django and still trying to wrap my head around certain aspects of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your question.

Use a session that will persist the value (as long as the session is active).

```
request.session['auth_type'] = 'SecureID'
```

Then you can always make a decision based on the session value you stored earlier.

```
if request.session['auth_type'] == 'SecureID':
    # do two factor auth stuff
    pass
else:
    # do normal stuff
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm dumb. I had read somewhere something that made me feel using session variables wasn't that simple, and couldn't find any information on it.

Comment: Lol :) (Maybe you need some rest). but this is the reference from the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: ... Thank you. I'm not sure how I didn't find that. Everything seems to be working now. Much appreciated.